# Boot defrag before or after full defragmentation

Tags: windows-7, defragment

As part of regular housekeeping I often run defraggler. I also run a boot time defrag. Is there any difference what order these should be run.

I usually run boot-defrag first as I feel the normal defrag can then move files around the system files later. Is there any truth in this?

Comment: If you run the boot time defrag why would you run the normal defrag routine?

Comment: The boot time defrag only affects system files which cannot be moved whilst the machine is loaded, the normal routine affects everything else.

Comment: My personal experience is entirely different.  To answer you question though it doesn't matter